# Hibernate, Criteria API, Sorting Enum Field Arbitrarily

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

What is the best way to sort a field arbitrarily?

Example:

Each `Content` has a `Status`. `Status`'s `id` is an enum. Business wants to see a list of `Content` sorted in the order `Status.Id.REJECTED`, `Status.Id.IN_WORK` and then `Status.Id.PENDING`.

As you can see, it's not sorted alphabetically. And someone may change their mind and want it sorted differently or throw some more status' in.

What is the best way to handle this situation? The only solutions I can come up with are adding an `order` to `Status` or to separately query each `Status` and then programatically stitch it together. But that seems dirty.

I understand there is some inherit absurdity with this premise but it is not mine and I have no control over it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I found the cleanest way to be to add an `int` `status.order` and then order the status' by that column. This provided me with:

- The ability to use only the Criteria API
- Cleaner code which doesn't worry about the business reasons behind the ordering in the data layer
- The ability to change the ordering on-the-fly by changing the values in the database.

The last point ended up being the real seller for me since the business side has a habit of incompletely thinking through their requirements and needing to change them several times during development and after launch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ordinal`. But as you said, it might change over time.

Then you can change the query, and let the `DB` do it. It is easier do it with `HQL` or `SQL`.

```
select 
    case 
       when a.FIELD = 'something' 
       then 1 
       else 0 
    end as myOrdr 
from A a 
order by myOrdr
```

Either way, you will have to touch code to change the order.

Comment: Outside of the "order" column I expect to have to change code and redeploy. Any links/refs for how to effectively do this with HQL?

Comment: I think HQL supports case. try a simple query.